# Edge Browser not loading font-face?

Tags: html, css, font-face, local, microsoft-edge

Using the normal CSS `font-face` does not appear to work properly on the new Windows 10 Edge browser. Works fine on IE11 and all other browsers. Has anyone else seen this? Seems like a bug in the browser.

Here’s the CSS we’ve been using.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Univers";
    src: url("../fonts/univers-webfont.eot");
    src: local(Univers), url("../fonts/univers-webfont.eot"), url("../fonts/univers-webfont.svg"), url("../fonts/univers-webfont.ttf"), url("../fonts/univers-webfont.woff");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.button_black {
    font-family: "Univers";
    font-size: 18px;
    color: @slb-off-black-1;
}
```

Comment: font face works fine in Edge - can you post a link to an example showing the issue?

Comment: http://slbportfolio.cloudapp.net/client/#/login for reference.  Inspect the element "Please log in..." and see that it should have a Univers font, but gets the default Times New Roman.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Short Answer

Put quotes around the font name when using the `local("Font Name")` syntax.

## Explanation

"Univers" renders fine in both Edge and Firefox. Your "Please log in..." element, though, is targeting "Univers Condensed", which renders in Edge only if you use `local("Univers Condensed")` with quotes. That is probably because Edge is more strict that Firefox is. [MDN says...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%40font-face)

> **src** URL for the remote font file location, or the name of a font on the user's computer in the form `local("Font Name")`. You can specify a font on the user's local computer by name using the `local()` syntax. If that font isn't found, other sources will be tried until one is found.

## Some Snips

Here are some screen shots that show the problematic CSS and HTML on your site.

#### Univers Condensed

[image: Univers Condensed]

#### No Quotes on `local()`

[image]